# List of all folders and files for x depth

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, file, directory

I want to have list of all folders and files for x depth.

If x is 2 than I will have information about all folders and files from first folder, and all folders and files from folders in first folder.

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will do what other answers are doing, but also return the folder names (as that appears to be part of what you are asking). This will require .Net 4.0. If you wish to keep track of which are folders and which are files you could return a tuple containing a list of files and a list of folders.

```
List<string> GetFilesAndFolders(string root, int depth)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    foreach(var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root))
    {
        list.Add(directory);
        if (depth > 0)
        {
            list.AddRange(GetFilesAndFolders(directory, depth-1));
        }
    }

    list.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(root));

    return list;
}
```

EDIT: Code that keeps the folders and files separate

```
Tuple<List<string>,List<string>> GetFilesAndFolders(string root, int depth)
{
    var folders = new List<string>();
    var files = new List<string>();
    foreach(var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root))
    {
        folders.Add(directory);
        if (depth > 0)
        {
                var result = GetFilesAndFolders(directory, depth-1);
                folders.AddRange(result.Item1);
                files.AddRange(result.Item2);
        }
    }

    files.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(root));

    return new Tuple<List<string>,List<string>>(folders, files);
}
```

Comment: And 'above' is not a good reference mechanism here. See the sorting Tabs.

Comment: As far as the sorting, that is easy enough to add, or bring back multi lists, the question said list of folders and files...so I wrote it that way. As far as the above reference, you are correct, was in a hurry and didn't think it through, will edit

Answer (score 2):

I feel as though this has been solved before.  Basically what you want to do is ask the current File if it is a directory, if true and x has not maxed out yet grab that File's SubDirectories. Also, you need to check if there are files present in that directory and retrieve them as well.

Answer (score 2):

if you just want the filenames you can do that with a recursive method. something like that:
(no garantee for total correctness, i write without compiler)

```
    public static List<String> GetSubfoldersAndFiles(DirectoryInfo di, int deep)
    {
       List<string> myContent = new List<string>();
       foreach(FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
       {
          myContent.Add(fi.FullName);
       }

       if(deep > 0)
       {
          foreach(DirectoryInfo subDi in di.GetDirectories())
          {
              myContent.AddRange(GetSubfoldersAndFiles(subDi, deep - 1).ToArray());
          }
       }

       return myContent;
    }
```

and the call would be like that:

```
List<string> content = GetSubfoldersAndFiles(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\"), 3);
```

Comment: Actually your `--deep` will make this fail. Another reason to avoid `++` and `--` , post or pre.

Comment: thats not true, the --deep will do exactly what i expect from. why should it fail?

Comment: You need to move the --deep call to outside the foreach, otherwise you will incorrectly search for subdirectories unless there is only 1 (just imagine calling it as your example lists with a depth of 3 and the top folder has 3 sub folders, by the time you get to the second subfolder you are only going to search it for a depth of 1, the 3rd you will not recursively search at all)

Comment: but at least this code works with also with 2.0, and YES there are still win2k server in production grmbl...;-)

Answer (score 1):

All subfolders

```
public List<string> listDir(string pPath)
        {
            List<string> dirList = new List<string>();
            listDir(pPath, dirList);
            return dirList;
        }
private void listDir(string pPath, List<string> pList)
        {
                string[] loDirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(pPath);
                foreach (string loDir in loDirs)
                {
                    pList.Add(loDir);
                    listDir(loDir, pList);
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending @pstrjds answer

```
private static IReadOnlyList<string> SearchFiles(string root, string pattern = "*", int depth = 1, params string[] exceptFolders)
{
    var files = Directory
        .EnumerateDirectories(root)
        .Where(it => !exceptFolders.Contains(Path.GetRelativePath(root, it)) && depth > 0)
        .SelectMany(it => SearchFiles(it, pattern, depth - 1, exceptFolders))
        .ToList();

    files.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(root, pattern));

    return files;
}
```

Comment: Path.GetRelativePath(root, it) doesn't seem to exist as part of Path. I simply removed it, and the exceptFolders arg, since I didn't need it.