# Walking through directory while controling depth - C#

Tags: c#, getfiles

I need to be able to get all files from a directory and sub directories, but I would like to give the user the option to choose the depth of sub-directories.
I.e., not just current directory or all directories, but he should be able to choose a depth of 1,2,3,4 directories etc.

I've seen many examples of walking through directory trees and none of them seemed to address this issue. And personally, I get confused with recursion... (which I currently use). I am not sure how I would track the depth during a recursive function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
David

Here is my current code (which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061957/get-all-files-and-directories-in-specific-path-fast/6062804?s=2|0.2136#6062804)):

```
    static void FullDirList(DirectoryInfo dir, string searchPattern, string excludeFolders, int maxSz, string depth)
    {

        try
        {
            foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles(searchPattern))
            {

                if (excludeFolders != "")
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(file.FullName, excludeFolders, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) continue;

                myStream.WriteLine(file.FullName);
                MasterFileCounter += 1;

                if (maxSz > 0 && myStream.BaseStream.Length >= maxSz)
                {
                    myStream.Close();
                    myStream = new StreamWriter(nextOutPutFile());
                }

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // make this a spearate streamwriter to accept files that failed to be read.
            Console.WriteLine("Directory {0}  \n could not be accessed!!!!", dir.FullName);
            return;  // We alredy got an error trying to access dir so dont try to access it again
        }

        MasterFolderCounter += 1;

        foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            //folders.Add(d);
            // if (MasterFolderCounter > maxFolders) 
            FullDirList(d, searchPattern, excludeFolders, maxSz, depth);
        }

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141648/list-of-all-folders-and-files-for-x-depth   might give you a hint

Comment: Notice recursion? Add parameter to recursive function, increment it on each subfolder call. This way you know how deep you are.

Comment: @Thorarins, Thanks! I cant believe I didnt find that - I searched tons!! - I am looking into it now and will post back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using a maxdepth varibale that could be decremented each recursive call and then you cannot just return once reached the desired depth.

```
static void FullDirList(DirectoryInfo dir, string searchPattern, string excludeFolders, int maxSz, int maxDepth)
{

    if(maxDepth == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles(searchPattern))
        {

            if (excludeFolders != "")
                if (Regex.IsMatch(file.FullName, excludeFolders, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) continue;

            myStream.WriteLine(file.FullName);
            MasterFileCounter += 1;

            if (maxSz > 0 && myStream.BaseStream.Length >= maxSz)
            {
                myStream.Close();
                myStream = new StreamWriter(nextOutPutFile());
            }

        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // make this a spearate streamwriter to accept files that failed to be read.
        Console.WriteLine("Directory {0}  \n could not be accessed!!!!", dir.FullName);
        return;  // We alredy got an error trying to access dir so dont try to access it again
    }

    MasterFolderCounter += 1;

    foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dir.GetDirectories())
    {
        //folders.Add(d);
        // if (MasterFolderCounter > maxFolders) 
        FullDirList(d, searchPattern, excludeFolders, maxSz, depth - 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Rather than passing  `depth` and `maxDepth` arguments, simply pass `maxDepth`, decrement by 1 on each recursion and check it is > 0

Comment: Changed to use @TimRogers suggestion

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your response. I've tried this out but it doesnt seem to be working. I am looking into it - will post back soon. - THANKS!

Comment: Ok, sorry guys - it works perfectly. I always get confused when it comes to recursion... but now its pretty simple! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Let's start out by refactoring the code a little bit to make its work a little easier to understand.

So, the key exercise here is to recursively return all of the files that match the patterns required, but only to a certain depth. Let's get those files first.

```
public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFullDirList(
    DirectoryInfo dir, string searchPattern, int depth)
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles(searchPattern))
    {
        yield return file;
    }

    if (depth > 0)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            foreach (FileInfo f in GetFullDirList(d, searchPattern, depth - 1))
            {
                yield return f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just simplified the job of recursing for your files.

But you'll notice that it didn't exclude files based on the `excludeFolders` parameter. Let's tackle that now. Let's start building `FullDirList`.

The first line would be

```
    var results =
        from fi in GetFullDirList(dir, searchPattern, depth)
        where String.IsNullOrEmpty(excludeFolders)
            || !Regex.IsMatch(fi.FullName, excludeFolders, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        group fi.FullName by fi.Directory.FullName;
```

This goes and gets all of the files, restricts them against `excludeFolders` and then groups all the files by the folders they belong to. We do this so that we can do this next:

```
    var directoriesFound = results.Count();
    var filesFound = results.SelectMany(fi => fi).Count();
```

Now I noticed that you were counting `MasterFileCounter` & `MasterFolderCounter`.

You could easily write:

```
    MasterFolderCounter+= results.Count();
    MasterFileCounter += results.SelectMany(fi => fi).Count();
```

Now, to write out these files it appears you are trying to aggregate the file names into separate files, but keeping a maximum length (`maxSz`) of the file.

Here's how to do that:

```
    var aggregateByLength =
        results
            .SelectMany(fi => fi)
            .Aggregate(new [] { new StringBuilder() }.ToList(),
                (sbs, s) =>
                {
                    var nl = s + Environment.NewLine;
                    if (sbs.Last().Length + nl.Length > maxSz)
                    {
                        sbs.Add(new StringBuilder(nl));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sbs.Last().Append(nl);
                    }
                    return sbs;
                });
```

Writing the files now becomes extremely simple:

```
    foreach (var sb in aggregateByLength)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(nextOutPutFile(), sb.ToString());
    }
```

So, the full thing becomes:

```
static void FullDirList(
    DirectoryInfo dir, string searchPattern, string excludeFolders, int maxSz, int depth)
{
    var results =
        from fi in GetFullDirList(dir, searchPattern, depth)
        where String.IsNullOrEmpty(excludeFolders)
            || !Regex.IsMatch(fi.FullName, excludeFolders, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        group fi.FullName by fi.Directory.FullName;

    var directoriesFound = results.Count();
    var filesFound = results.SelectMany(fi => fi).Count();

    var aggregateByLength =
        results
            .SelectMany(fi => fi)
            .Aggregate(new [] { new StringBuilder() }.ToList(),
                (sbs, s) =>
                {
                    var nl = s + Environment.NewLine;
                    if (sbs.Last().Length + nl.Length > maxSz)
                    {
                        sbs.Add(new StringBuilder(nl));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sbs.Last().Append(nl);
                    }
                    return sbs;
                });

    foreach (var sb in aggregateByLength)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(nextOutPutFile(), sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! what language is this!!  ☺ - Thanks for the work and the detailed explanation. I am going to try to learn this and understand what you wrote.   -   Is this faster/slower than the previous method?

Comment: @DaveyD - Unless you have hundreds of thousands of files you probably wouldn't spot a speed difference. My code should me more maintainable as it splits out the recursive code and linearizes the iterative code. Oh, yes, it is c#. 

Comment: Ok, thanks - talking more like 2-3000. I do like the setup of your code, its very nice. I am still trying to figure out what you wrote! This looks somewhat like sql....

Comment: @DaveyD - The `results` part is using LINQ, which is like SQL. Have you used LINQ before?

Comment: I understand. No, I've never used linq before. Seems very interesting powerful and useful!!.  I dont know much sql either. I do know a little to get around, but far from comfortable.